# While loop through an array and move back then forward during the while?

Tags: php, arrays, gd

Right, so I've been wrecking my head over this for the last few days.

So I have these three strings

```
$string_one = 'Some text';
$string_two = 'Some more text';
$string_three = 'Even more text';
```

Which are going through `imagettfbbox()` to set their heights and widths.

I want the output in my GD image to be `Some text Some more text Even more text`, so basically I want them all on one line. So I'm trying to work out the x position for each string, based on the previous strings length, which has to be relative to and `$x` position.

Currently, I'm trying to do the following :

1. Adding the two (or more) widths together
2. Dividing the total by 2
3. Minus-ing the answer from `$x`, this gives the starting point for the first string on the line.
4. To set the second strings starting point, I'm adding the first strings length to the the starting point.

However in order to do that, I'm having to go back to the previous values, get the width, add that to the current width and divide by two, and then set values for the previous and current array variable.

**So each time the while loops, I want want to move the array pointer back, get the width values, determine x positions, then move the array pointer forwards and set x positions.**

So I'm trying to use `prev()` and `next()` to traverse the array.

I'm doing the following :

`$gb` is set depending upon which string the for loop is going over. So if it's the 2nd case, it goes back 1, to the first one. if it's the 5th it goes back 3, but that's not important here.

`$o` is the counter that iterates at the end of the while loop that these two for loops sit in.

`$text` is a 2 dimensional array that starts like this :

```
Array
(
    [ven-pub] => Array
        (
            [value] => 
            [font-size] => 30
        )

    [More array values]....
)
```

But I'm aiming for it to look like this by the end

```
Array
(
    [ven-pub] => Array
        (
            [value] => 
            [font-size] => 30
            [h] => 38
            [w] => 514
            [x] => 1514
            [y] => 1611
        )

    [More array values]....
)
```

I'll comment in the code what I'm trying to do, but assume that this while is looping through the second array variable.

```
$gb = 1;//In this instance $gb is going back once.
$o = 1;//Set the counter to one, because count will not include 0, right?
$arr_c = count($text);//Set the maximum number of times we should loop.
while($o <= $arr_c){//Meanwhile...
    $key = key($text);//Getting the current key
    $text[$key]['font-size'] = $text[$key]['font-size']*3;//Text related stuff
    //Getting the height and width of my string  
    $dimensions = imagettfbbox($text[$key]['font-size'], 0, $font, $text[$key]['value']);
    $text[$key]['h'] = ($dimensions[7]-$dimensions[1])*-1;//Setting the height...
    $text[$key]['w'] = ($dimensions[2]-$dimensions[0]);//...and width

    for($gb;$gb<=$o;$gb++){
        $key = key($text);//I've found getting the key again helps..
        /* Here I'm looping backward just once using prev()
           and adding the widths into one variable */
        $widths[] = $text[$key]['w'];
        prev($text);
    }

    $total_width = array_sum($widths);
    $x = ($new_x - ($total_width/2)); //Dividing it by two to get my start position.
    /*Setting the current $key's ['x'] position, which should be 
      the first array variable, not the second.*/  
    $text[$key]['x'] = $x;


    $gb = $cgb;//Resets $gb to its original number.
    $combined_widths[] = $text[$key]['w'];//Saving the starting width for the next array variable

    for($gb;$gb<=$o;$gb++){
        next($text);//Moving forwards to the next array variable.
        /* Adding the previous array variables width to $x to generate the
           second array variables ['x'] position.  
        */
        $text[$key]['x'] = $x+array_sum($combined_widths);
        $combined_widths[] = $text[$key]['w'];//Adding the new variables width to the previous          

    }
//By here, the array pointer should be back where it started for this loop.

next($text)//Move the array pointer forward ready for the next loop.
$o++
}
```

My problem arises when it starts to either go back to far, or tells me the index is undefined. Ridiculously confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, honestly, I don't understand your code. It's broken at so many points that I'm not able to fix it right away. Plus I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Please review the following code which I created based on your code and what I've understood so far. Maybe we can come to something that's closer to what you want to achieve or maybe just the different coding style is enough for you to reach your goal.

```
<?php

// Ensure we start from the beginning of the array.
reset($text);

// Helpers...
$widths = $next_x = 0;

foreach ($text as $key => $attributes) {
  $text[$key]["font-size"] *= 3;

  // Where is $font coming fromt?
  $dimensions  = imagettfbbox($text[$key]["font-size"], 0, $font, $text[$key]["value"]);

  $text[$key]["h"] = abs($dimensions[7] - $dimensions[1]);
  $text[$key]["w"] = $dimensions[2] - $dimensions[0];

  // Directly add it, we iterate forward, no need for your complicated and slow loop in a loop.
  $widths += $text[$key]["w"];

  // Where is $new_x coming from?
  $text[$key]["x"] = $next_x - $widths / 2;

  // All we wanted, isn't it.
  $next_x = $text[$key]["x"] + $text[$key]["w"];
}

?>
```

General advice: always try to write easy to understand code. Don't start fiddling around with `prev()` and `next()` or a loop-in-a-loop unless it's not totally necessary (for whatever reason). Don't hesitate to introduce intermediate variables that help you and others to understand your code (name them accordingly so everybody knows what they're doing without any comments).

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't that concise. `$new_x` is the middle of the drawing area; so I have an image and a box on that image specifically for writing text, `$new_x` is the co-ordinate which is in the center of the box that I'd like to write my text in. As I don't know the total length of the line, because the loop hasn't looked at the widths of future variables, I can't give the first variable its x position.